# How to get killed methods back in django-endless-pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-endless-pagination

After ajax added new containers it killed methods initialized for them, what can I do to make django-endless-pagination add some JQuery to its generated containers?
For example i have:

```js
$(".fact").each(function() {
   $(this).css('border-top', '5px solid ' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
});
```

and i want to add this to each .fact generated after ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Attaching callbacks section](https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/javascript.html#attaching-callbacks) from the documentation :)

Supposing this is your **endless pagination initialisation** you can add some code to be executed on each new reload.

```
<script>
    $.endlessPaginate({
        paginateOnScroll: true,
        paginateOnScrollMargin: 100,
        paginateOnScrollChunkSize: 5,
        // add your code in onCompleted 
        onCompleted: function(context, fragment) {
            $(".fact").each(function() {
                $(this).css('border-top', '5px solid ' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
                });
            });

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your endless pagination script, templates... and any errors that you see... Saying that it is not working won't help to solve the issue. Also compare your code with the documentation to see if you did somthing wrong.

Comment: I made it, I was stupid enough to forget to declare colors list. But still thank you =)